# Difficulties with an unruly program

Tags: python

I have been working on this code for a couple of hours now, and I am rather unsure what the problem is.

```
import random#imports random
import os#Imports os
print("Welcome to the maths quiz") # Welcomes user to quiz
score = (0)


def details():
    plr_name = input ("Please Input Name:") # Asks user for name
    plr_class = input("Input class number: ") # Asks the user for class numer
return (plr_name, plr_class)

def Q():
    while qno < 10: # loops while qno is under 10
        ran_num1 = random.randint(1,99) # Generates the first random number
        ran_num2 = random.randint(1,99) # Generates the second random number
        ran_fun = random.choice("X-+") # Picks a random function
        print(ran_num1,ran_fun,ran_num2,"=") # Prints the Sum for the user
        if ran_fun == "X":
            sum_ans = ran_num1 * ran_num2 # Does the sum if it is a multiplication
        if ran_fun == "+":
            sum_ans = ran_num1 + ran_num2 # Does the sum if it is a addition
        if ran_fun == "-":
            sum_ans = ran_num1 - ran_num2 # Does the sum if it is a subtraction
        plr_ans = int(input()) # Gets the user's answer
        if plr_ans == sum_ans:
            print("Correct!") # Prints correct
            score = score + 1 # Adds 1 to score
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
        qno = qno + 1 # Adds 1 to qno


def plr_list_make(lines, listoreder):
    index = 0
    plr_names =[]
    plr_scores =[]

    for line in lines:
        if listorder == 1:
            column =0
            rev = False
    else:
       column = 1
       rev = True
    return sorted(zip(plr_names, plr_scores),key = lambda x:(x[column]),reverse = rev)


def fileUP(plr_name, score, line ):
    found = False
    index = 0
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(plr_name):
            line = line.strip("\n") + ","+str(score+"\n")
            lines[index] = line
            found = True
        index = index + 1
    if not found:
        lines.append(plr_name+"|" +str(score)+"\n")
    return lines


def save (plr_name, plr_class, score):
    filename = "QuizScore_"+plr_class+".txt"
    try:
        fileI = open(filename)
    except IOError:
        fileI = open(filename, "w+")
        fileI = open(filename)
    lines = fileI.readlines()
    fileI.close

    lines = FileUP(plr_name, score, lines)
    fileO = open(filename, "w")
    fileO.writelines(lines)
    fileO.close


def disp_list(): ## intialise_list
    student_list=[] 
    filename = "QuizScore_"+plr_class+".txt"
    try:
        ## open file read into list "lines"
        input_file = open(filename)
        lines = input_file.readlines()   ## read file into list "lines"
        input_file.close

        student_list = create_student_list(lines, listorder) ### update "lines" with student list as requested by user

        ## output sorted list
        for counter in range(len(student_list)):
            print ("Name and Score: ", student_list[counter][0], student_list[counter][1])    

    except IOError:
        print ("no class file!!!")



def menu():
    print ("1 Test")
    print ("2 Alphabetical")
    print ("3 Highscore")
    print ("4 Avg Score")

def Run():
    selection = 0
    while selection != 5:
        menu()
        option = int(input("Please select option: "))     
        if option == 1:
            name, plr_class = details()
            save(name, plr_class, Q())
        else:
            plr_class = input("input class ")
            disp_list(plr_class, option-1)
Run()
```

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\CharlieStockham\cgsca\ca2.py", line 117, in 
>           Run()
>   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\CharlieStockham\cgsca\ca2.py", line 113, in Run
>           save(name, plr_class, Q())
>   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\CharlieStockham\cgsca\ca2.py", line 74, in save
>           lines = FileUP(plr_name, score, lines)
>       NameError: global name 'FileUP' is not defined

Comment: question title is cute, but does not state the problem.

Comment: When I run the program the menu feature works, but when you get past entering the student name and student class it will crash.

Comment: Can you please give us those errors?

Comment: Your function Q() doesn't return anything, but you pass its return value (`None`) to save(). Perhaps this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Here are the errors that are occurring: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\IBliminse\cgsca\ca2.py", line 115, in <module>
    Run()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\IBliminse\cgsca\ca2.py", line 110, in Run
    name, plr_class = details()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the errors there. Which lines are lines 115 and 110?

Comment: Just a tip, comments for a single line of code are only needed if that line is doing something very complicated. General rule, comments should explain why something is happening, not what. The 'what' is (usually) obvious.

Comment: Did you consider using some IDE (for example: Pycharm CE)?

Answer (score 2):

Line 110:

```
        name, plr_class = details()
```

But the `details` function does not return anything - so Python tries to assign the default return value `None` to the tuple `name, plr_class`. It can't do this, because `None` is not an iterable (you can't assign two things to it). To fix it, add the following line to your `details` function:

```
    return (plr_name, plr_class)
```

(I haven't tested this.)

Comment: 99 bugs in the code fix one bug run it again 137 bugs in the code :)

Answer (score 1):

I like your game but it's buggy as a mofo :P

`score` and `qno` aren't properly defined. Define them in the functions that need them, define them globally or pass them to the relevant functions as arguments.

`details()` doesn't return anything but you still attempt to use its output to define two other variables. Add `return (plr_name, plr_class)` to `details()`

Every time you cast user input to int without checking its value, your program will crash if an int can't be cast. This applies here:

```
option = int(input("Please select option: "))
```

here

```
plr_ans = int(input())#Gets the user's answer
```

and elsewhere.

Since your program is input-heavy you could make a a function to which you pass the expected datatype and an optional string to display to the user. This way you wouldn't have to write try/except 10 times and your program wouldn't crash on unexpected input.

In `def fileUP(plr_name, score, line ):` you have `for line in lines:` but `lines` isn't defined. Thus, the `save()` function that calls `FileUP()` also fails. Also, `FileUP` and `fileUP` are not the same thing. You call the function with a capital "f" but the defintion of the function calls it `fileUP` with a lower case "f".

While we're at it, the file handling in `def save (plr_name, plr_class, score):`looks weird. The standard way of opening files for simple reading and writing in Python is via `with open()`.

`disp_list()` should take one or two arguments but it doesn't at the moment so this error is raised:

```
TypeError: disp_list() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

These 2 positional arguments were given here:

```
disp_list(plr_class, option-1)
```